# How do I Resample two .asc elevation models in python? It does not need to be complex something like Nearest neighbour is good

Tags: python, gis, interpolation, raster, spatial-interpolation

I am very new to python and coding.  I am trying to make the ice DEM(test5) fit over top of the NZ DEM so that the points line up. The data has different cell sizes. This is what I have so far. All it does is put the data into a numpy array at the moment. I am unsure on what my next steps should be. Attached is a link to a google drive with the files.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E_IxZoA1PnA4gufFHBtLVRtVTUvFNFPs?usp=sharing

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    """
    Created on Wed May 19 15:40:19 2021

    @author: pyoli286
    """
    import numpy as np
    # pathDem = str(input("input the path to file for example 'U:/SURV319/lab1work/lab1/': "))
    # nameDem = str(input("input .asc file. For example 'nzdem1000.asc': "))

    # pathIce = str(input("input the path to file for example 'U:/SURV319/lab1work/lab1/': "))
    # nameIce = str(input("input .asc file. For example 'nzdem1000.asc': "))

    pathDem = "/Users/liampyott/Documents/2021/319/Lab3/work/"
    nameDem = "nzdem1000.asc"

    pathIce = "/Users/liampyott/Documents/2021/319/Lab3/work/"
    nameIce = "test5.asc"

    def demNZ (inDemNz):
        """
        takes the DEM for New Zealand and reads the first 6 lines and ads to a numpy array

        """
        f = open(inDemNz, 'r')    
        
        headerline1 = f.readline()
        headerline1 = headerline1.split()
        NCOLS = int(headerline1[1])
        
        headerline2 = f.readline()
        headerline2 = headerline2.split()
        NROWS = int(headerline2[1])
        
        
        headerline3 = f.readline()
        headerline3 = headerline3.split()
        XLLCORNER = int(headerline3[1])
        
        
        headerline4 = f.readline()
        headerline4 = headerline4.split()
        YLLCORNER = int(headerline4[1])
        
        
        headerline5 = f.readline()
        headerline5 = headerline5.split()
        CELLSIZE = int(headerline5[1])
        
        
        headerline6 = f.readline()
        headerline6 = headerline6.split()
        NODATA_VALUE = int(headerline6[1])

        nzDem = []
        for row in f:
            row = row.split()
            for col in row:
                nzDem.append(float(col))
        nzdem2d = np.reshape(nzDem, (NROWS, NCOLS))

        return nzdem2d

    def demIce (inDemIce):
        """
        takes the DEM for ice and reads the first 6 lines and and ads to a numpy array

        """
        f = open(inDemIce, 'r')    
        
        headerline1 = f.readline()
        headerline1 = headerline1.split()
        NCOLS = int(headerline1[1])
        
        headerline2 = f.readline()
        headerline2 = headerline2.split()
        NROWS = int(headerline2[1])
        
        
        headerline3 = f.readline()
        headerline3 = headerline3.split()
        XLLCORNER = int(headerline3[1])
        
        
        headerline4 = f.readline()
        headerline4 = headerline4.split()
        YLLCORNER = int(headerline4[1])
        
        
        headerline5 = f.readline()
        headerline5 = headerline5.split()
        CELLSIZE = int(headerline5[1])
        
        
        headerline6 = f.readline()
        headerline6 = headerline6.split()
        NODATA_VALUE = int(headerline6[1])

        iceDem = []
        for row in f:
            row = row.split()
            for col in row:
                iceDem.append(float(col))
        ice2d = np.reshape(iceDem, (NROWS, NCOLS))
        f.close
        
        return ice2d


        


    inDemNz = (pathDem+nameDem)
    inDemIce = (pathIce+nameIce)
    demNZ(inDemNz)
    demIce(inDemIce)
```